# How to order mongodb $lookup query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

### Overview

A few devices are collecting data and sending it to a Node/MongoDb endpoint. Then, the user would use an endpoint to get all that data into a json.

### Models

#### Device Model

```
const deviceSchema = new Schema({
    group: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' },
    deviceId: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: String,
    notes: String,
    pac: String,
    endCertificate: String,
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number
});
```

#### Message Model

```
const messageSchema = new Schema({
    deviceId: { type: String, required: true },
    raw: { type: String, required: true },
    receivedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});
```

> One device can have N messages

### Problem to solve

I want to get a json that has all the devices and have an array containing
all the messages that belongs to that device.

```
[
   {
      "id":"5b86c323e95759603ad7ea54",
      "deviceId":"Device 01",
      "name":"Device bla",
      "notes":"...",
      "pac":"pac",
      "lat":-20.817396,
      "endCertificate":"cert",
      "lng":-27.031321,
      "messages":[
         {
            "id":"5b869a42e0b94041b5f21eed",
            "deviceId":"Device 01",
            "raw":"1111111",
            "receivedAt":"2018-08-29T13:04:43.641Z",
            "__v":0
         },
         {
            "id":"5b8c782fef4f8e98783f6f35",
            "deviceId":"Device 01",
            "raw":"2222222",
            "receivedAt":"2018-09-01T09:04:43.641Z",
            "__v":0
         },
         {
            "id":"5b8c7840ef4f8e98783f6f3e",
            "deviceId":"Device 01",
            "raw":"3333333",
            "receivedAt":"2018-09-02T09:04:43.641Z",
            "__v":0
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"5b8c28ec38c51813cd159bac",
      "deviceId":"Device 02",
      "name":"Device ...",
      "notes":"...",
      "lat":-27.812296,
      "lng":-27.073314,
      "__v":0,
      "messages":[
         {
            "id":"5b8c784cef4f8e98783f6f43",
            "deviceId":"Device 02",
            "raw":"1111111",
            "receivedAt":"2018-09-01T09:04:43.641Z",
            "__v":0
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

### My solution

To get a json as the one above I have:

```
const [results, itemCount] = await Promise.all([
    Device.aggregate([
        { $match: {} },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'messageschemas',
                localField: 'deviceId',
                foreignField: 'deviceId',
                as: 'messages'
            }
        }
    ]).limit(req.query.limit).skip(req.skip)
        .exec(),
    Device.countDocuments(match)
    ]);
res.setHeader('X-Total-Count', itemCount);
res.send(results);
```

#### My question

How can I order the messages I get from the $lookup into messages[] by
'receivedAt'?

Comment: Could you share your mongodb version.

Comment: Sure I can: v3.4.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `messages` array and can apply [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) with `receivedAt` field and finally [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to rollback again into the array.

```
Device.aggregate([
  { "$match": { }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "messageschemas",
    "localField": "deviceId",
    "foreignField": "deviceId",
    "as": "messages"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$messages" },
  { "$sort": { "messages.receivedAt": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "messages": { "$push": "$messages" }
  }}
])
```

Which can be simply done with the **3.6** [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax

```
Device.aggregate([
  { "$match": { }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "messageschemas",
    "let": { "deviceId": "$deviceId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$deviceId", "$$deviceId" ] } } },
      { "$sort": { "receivedAt": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "messages"
  }}
])
```